# Silverlight Authentication Without RIA Services?

Tags: c#, forms-authentication, silverlight-5.0

I would like to know if it’s possible to do use authentication in Silverlight 5 without having to use RIA Services.  I am using Entity Framework to connect to my database. I am also using the Business Application template. I have created a custom membership provider through which I am able to validate user credentials and can add new users.  However, if I want to restrict content on the app based on which user is logged on, I have no way of doing. I believe that if I create a RIA Services Domain Context I can potentially check user information via WebContext.Current.User. Is there a way to get this type of information without RIA? Perhaps a WCF service of some sort?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once I wrote a tutorial on how to share forms authentication between your web app and a silverlight app. This works without ria, uses guarded wcf. You can even fine tune the access to individual roles.

http://netpl.blogspot.com/2010/04/aspnet-forms-authentication-sharing-for.html

Comment: Thanks for the insightful article. This kind of solves my problem in the sense that I can restrict users from getting to the app if they are not authenticated. That was definitely one of my goals. The other goal I had in mind was loading specific data based on which user is currently logged in. Your solution passes detailed error information from the server to the client. Is there a way to pass user info in a similar fashion?

Comment: HttpContext.Current.User. Since you rely on FormsAuthentication, you gain user information as usual.

Comment: As far as I'm aware, HttpContext.Current.User is only available from the server. All my business logic, etc. is within the Silverlight client. Is it possible to pass this info from the server to the client?

Comment: Of course it is, that is why you set up a wcf from the server to the client. But this would be insecure. It is the client who should prove its identity to the server rather than the server trying to convince the client who he/she is. Imagine someone recompiles your application and misuses your client side logic by freely substituting parts of your logic with something malicious.

Comment: Gotcha, I don't know why I hadn't thought of the insecure option of simply passing that info through wcf. That seems to be working ok for me. Don't worry, I'm only working on a training exercise so insecure but effective might work for now. Thank you!